# How to create mutable String with specific lifetime?

Tags: rust

I have a function to read file content. I need to return the content from this function by reference and I just can't figure out how to create mutable `String` with certain lifetime inside the function.

```
fn main() {
    let filename = String::new();
    let content: &String = read_file_content(&filename);
    println!("{:?}", content);
}

fn read_file_content<'a>(_filename: &'a String) -> &'a String {
    let mut content: &'a String = &String::new();

    //....read file content.....
    //File::open(filename).unwrap().read_to_string(&mut content).unwrap();

    return &content;
}
```

Output:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:8:36
   |
8  |     let mut content: &'a String = &String::new();
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ does not live long enough
...
14 | }
   | - temporary value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 7:1...
  --> src/main.rs:7:1
   |
7  | / fn read_file_content<'a>(_filename: &'a String) -> &'a String {
8  | |     let mut content: &'a String = &String::new();
9  | |
10 | |     //....read file content.....
...  |
13 | |     return &content;
14 | | }
   | |_^
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6fc23106ab3636f44d7cf1d3006a2ba4&version=stable)

Comment: Why are you trying to that?  Just move the return value and ditch the reference semantics.

Comment: @HenriMenke I agree that this is not good example, but I'm just playing with Rust I was curious is it possible to do or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, you have a logical error in your code.  You are trying to bound the lifetime of the file's contents to the lifetime of the filename, for which there is absolutely no reason.  The reason why your code cannot compile is that the line

```
let mut content: &'a String = &String::new();
```

effectively reads

```
let mut anonymous = String::new();
let mut content: &'a String = &anonymous;
```

The variable which I called `anonymous` does not live longer than the function.  The only way to make it live longer than the function is to use a reference-counted type to wrap the string, so that it is not dropped when it goes out of scope but only when the reference count decreases to 0.

---

I suggest you simply ditch the reference semantics and use values instead.  Also calling `unwrap` in a function other than `main` is not good practice, so I topped up your code with some error handling.

In case you worry about performance, the return value will be moved (not copied) so there is absolutely no performance penalty in this simplification.

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let filename = String::new();
    let content = read_file_content(&filename).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", content);
}

fn read_file_content(filename: &str) -> std::io::Result<String> {
    //....read file content.....
    let mut content = String::new();
    let mut file = File::open(filename)?;
    file.read_to_string(&mut content)?;
    Ok(content)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2ba5443e3b22984179bc691f1996c063&version=stable)

Comment: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec) or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/3650362) (yes, it was in the original, but I think it would be in keeping with your other changes to make this improvement as well.)

Comment: @trentcl Of course, thank you!

Comment: thanks for the advice